# Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\option1\db_def.php on line 49

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me on this? I am a php beginner. Error I am getting is:

> Warning: "mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\option1\db_def.php on line 49"

i.e where if statement starts.

```
<?php
include ('config.php');
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$date= $_POST["date"];
$sno= $_POST["sno"];
// and so on

$sql= mysql_query("INSERT INTO      data(date,sno,block,name,so_wo_do,plot_size,hno,hno1,street,mohalla,ws_id,sid,ws_conn,s_conn,dispo_conn,elec_acc,residential_commercial,trade_licence,hno2,street2,mohalla2,contact,email,year_construction,structure,nature_unit,usage,basement,gnd_floor,first_floor,sec_floor,third_floor,any_floor,total,area_sft,oid_no,remarks) VALUES('$_POST[date]','$_POST[sno]','$_POST[block]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[so_wo_do]','$_POST[plot_size]','$_POST[hno]','$_POST[hno1]','$_POST[street]','$_POST[mohalla]','$_POST[ws_id]','$_POST[sid]','$_POST[ws_conn]','$_POST[s_conn]','$_POST[dispo_conn]','$_POST[elec_acc]','$_POST[residential_commercial]','$_POST[trade_licence]','$_POST[hno2]','$_POST[street2]','$_POST[mohalla2]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[year_construction]','$_POST[structure]','$_POST[nature_unit]','$_POST[usage]','$_POST[basement]','$_POST[gnd_floor]','$_POST[first_floor]','$_POST[sec_floor]','$_POST[third_floor]','$_POST[any_floor]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[area_sft]','$_POST[oid_no]','$_POST[remarks]')");

if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    echo("Member Registered!");
} 
else
{
    echo("Input data is fail");
}
}
mysqli_close($con);

 ?>
```

Comment: You're mixing `mysql_query` & `mysqli_query`.

Comment: Also, why are you assigning the $_POST values to php variables but then using the $_POST values in your sql string?  By doing this and without any data validation/sanitization, this leaves you wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: He said he's new to PHP, so an advice on SQL injection is nice but asking him "why" will surely leave you without an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

you are using mysqli_* functions and also mixing it with `mysql_query`

here `$sql= mysql_query(----)` your are using again `$Sql` in `mysqli_query();` that is incorrect.

please change it to `$sql =  "INSERT INTO      data( // al col names) VALUES(//all vals)"`

and use `$sql` it inside `mysqli_query($con,$sql)`.
Remove `mysql_query()`

Answer (score 0):

You should try this. Can you please define why you include('config.php') file? and you are making new connection also ..

```
<?php
    //include ('config.php');
    $con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql");

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $date= $_POST["date"];
    $sno= $_POST["sno"];
    // and so on

    $sql= "INSERT INTO      data(date,sno,block,name,so_wo_do,plot_size,hno,hno1,street,mohalla,ws_id,sid,ws_conn,s_conn,dispo_conn,elec_acc,residential_commercial,trade_licence,hno2,street2,mohalla2,contact,email,year_construction,structure,nature_unit,usage,basement,gnd_floor,first_floor,sec_floor,third_floor,any_floor,total,area_sft,oid_no,remarks) VALUES('$_POST[date]','$_POST[sno]','$_POST[block]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[so_wo_do]','$_POST[plot_size]','$_POST[hno]','$_POST[hno1]','$_POST[street]','$_POST[mohalla]','$_POST[ws_id]','$_POST[sid]','$_POST[ws_conn]','$_POST[s_conn]','$_POST[dispo_conn]','$_POST[elec_acc]','$_POST[residential_commercial]','$_POST[trade_licence]','$_POST[hno2]','$_POST[street2]','$_POST[mohalla2]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[year_construction]','$_POST[structure]','$_POST[nature_unit]','$_POST[usage]','$_POST[basement]','$_POST[gnd_floor]','$_POST[first_floor]','$_POST[sec_floor]','$_POST[third_floor]','$_POST[any_floor]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[area_sft]','$_POST[oid_no]','$_POST[remarks]')";

    $query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    if($query)
        echo("Member Registered!");
    } 
    else
    {
        echo("Input data is fail");
    }
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

     ?>
```

Comment: I have tried every thing, there is no error showing when i submit, but no data is going in database.

Comment: echo $query before if() condition and check what is printing

Comment: INSERT INTO data(date,sno,block,oname,so_wo_do,plot_size,hno,hno1,street,mohalla,ws_id,sid,ws_conn,s_conn,dispo_conn,elec_acc,resi_comm,trade_licence,hno2,street2,mohalla2,contact,email,yr_cons,structure,nature_unit,usage,basement,gnd_floor,first_floor,sec_floor,third_floor,any_floor,total,area_sft,oid_no,remarks) VALUES('2014/01/30','2','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')Data Entered Successfully!

Comment: Data Entered Successfully? is data inserted in database? there is any limit to view record of that table.?

Comment: No i have made a blank entry, with date and serial no. only

Answer (score 0):

please use only mysqli query

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO      data(date,sno,block,name,so_wo_do,plot_size,hno,hno1,street,mohalla,ws_id,sid,ws_conn,s_conn,dispo_conn,elec_acc,residential_commercial,trade_licence,hno2,street2,mohalla2,contact,email,year_construction,structure,nature_unit,usage,basement,gnd_floor,first_floor,sec_floor,third_floor,any_floor,total,area_sft,oid_no,remarks) VALUES('$_POST[date]','$_POST[sno]','$_POST[block]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[so_wo_do]','$_POST[plot_size]','$_POST[hno]','$_POST[hno1]','$_POST[street]','$_POST[mohalla]','$_POST[ws_id]','$_POST[sid]','$_POST[ws_conn]','$_POST[s_conn]','$_POST[dispo_conn]','$_POST[elec_acc]','$_POST[residential_commercial]','$_POST[trade_licence]','$_POST[hno2]','$_POST[street2]','$_POST[mohalla2]','$_POST[contact]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[year_construction]','$_POST[structure]','$_POST[nature_unit]','$_POST[usage]','$_POST[basement]','$_POST[gnd_floor]','$_POST[first_floor]','$_POST[sec_floor]','$_POST[third_floor]','$_POST[any_floor]','$_POST[total]','$_POST[area_sft]','$_POST[oid_no]','$_POST[remarks]')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the problem was the range, I had to move the `$query = ($con, "SELECT blah blah");` a couple of lines.
Never had this before in the old way of coding, this is `msqli` vs `msql`.
You just need to relearn everything you have learned if you only know how to code the old way.

This reply is for the topic title only, my post is not a reaction or solving answer to this topic.
It might help somebody else if ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a range or global problem, because it is returning an empty query.
But without more information on `db_def.php` on line 49 it is hard to say.

```
include ('config.php');
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("could not connect to mysql");
```

You need to create a global variable in "db_def.php" that declaires $con or create one every time you connect or query in 'db_def.php'